# Reheating Food Cooked Before Passover

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, passover

Let's say a family cooked some non chametz food before kashering their dishes before Pesach and saved the leftovers to be reheated later.

A few days go by and Pesach gets closer, and they kasher all of their pots and pans in preparation for Pesach, but Pesach is still days away. And now they want to reheat the leftovers. If they do so, do they have to rekasher whatever pan it is cooked for Passover again?

What about reheating the food during Passover?

Looking more specifically for Sephardic Sources, but would be interested in all sources presented.

Comment: This is really a difficult question and should be addressed to a rov. @Aaron It depends if these foods are considered chomets or not.  When they were boiled in a chomets pot, how long before that actual chomets was used in the pot.  Dovor charif and many other things.